# Android: ListFragment, how to show only one list item on whole screen

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

how can I set ListFragment to show each of its items on whole screen? And of course, when you swipe up and down, whole item should be available at a time, the list shouldn't stop scrolling in the middle of two items. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I think you're looking for a vertical `ViewPager`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889530/vertical-viewpager-implementation

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. Add a OnScorllListener and implement logic to "settle" the list
   after a scroll.
2. Make a vertical ViewPager. You could copy the source code and flip everything from using X to using Y.